# Windows 10 Microsoft IME Japanese changed (via registry) QWERTY to QWERTZ; Can't switch to Kana Input via Shortcut

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout, ime, japanese

Playing games in Japanese I noticed, that the MS IME for Japanese sometimes uses the QWERTZ Layout (I'm using a German Keyboard) instead of the QWERTY it usually is stuck to.
I couldn't find a pattern on when it happens, it just happens sometimes. And of course, the only Layout options are (still) either us qwerty or jp qwerty.

I googled to make the occasional happening permanent. Then I found an AZERTY user who made a registry change (good god, if my keyboard were azerty, I'd have bought a second keyboard).

It works, except that I can't change the Romaji / Kana Input Modes via <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> and need to left click the Taskbar icon (especially bothersome playing games - need to change to windowed mode, click the icon and revert to fullscreen mode)

I changed some settings, in the IME Settings - I tried to set up different keys and combinations to make that change.

For reference I'll add the steps for my registry change:

> - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layouts\00000411
> - "Layout Text" should read "Japanese"
> - Change the value of "Layout File" from "KBDJPN.DLL" to "KBDGR.DLL"

On a side note: Why the hell isn't MS just making a Setting to make IME fit with your HW Keyboard layout... people are having this problem since the 90's and it shouldn't be too hard to implement and would please many customers.......

Comment: Ever find a solution for this?